# Django RetrieveDestroyAPIView not working while requesting with vue.js

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vue-cli

I had created a Django rest API, and through vue.js function, I implemented to delete the object by the id given to it, on clicking button I made a function to pass the URL with id given to API to delete the object. Django rest API works in its rest API site, but when it comes to access the API through vue.js function it's not removing an object and even no error also showing

**#HTML code**

```
<td v-on:click="deleteCountry(c.id)"><center><p class="fas fa-times"></p></center></td> // c.id is is dynamic id i am getting by django db
```

**#vue.js code**

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    title:'app',
},
 methods:{
deleteCountry(id){
      this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/countries/'+id+'/delete/');
    },
}
 }
}
</script>
```

**django rest api viewsets code**

```
from rest_framework .generics import(
    ListAPIView,
    RetrieveAPIView,
    DestroyAPIView,
    UpdateAPIView,
    RetrieveDestroyAPIView,
    RetrieveUpdateAPIView)

class CountryDeleteAPIView(RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = countries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountryDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
```

Comment: Have you implemented any kind of authentication in your restful API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `HTTP GET` for deleting.So, change

```
this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/countries/'+id+'/delete/');
```

to

```
this.$http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/countries/'+id+'/delete/');
```

Comment: Dear Jerin thank you so much, now i am thinking about my self that how stupidly i had done debug, i had forgotten at searching errors for basic instead i thought it might be a server side error

Comment: Be a keen observer brother ;) Happy coding :)